# A pr need modify to merged but the branch is behind the main branch

Tags: git, github, pull-request, git-commit

I fork a repo and clone it to local, then I change code and create a branch, I git add, git commit and git push the update to the new branch, later I return my github and commit a pull request. But this pull request isn't be merged and I need to modify more code to be merged. For common situation, I modify code in local and push my update to the same branch continually can finish. But I find that the new branch(Associated to my pr) is behind the main branch, so if I push directly,  it will be conflict. But when I try to sync fork, my previous commits will be discarded. What can I do to solve this problem?

[when i sync fork](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ES6Gk.png)
This branch is 9 commits ahead and 6 commits behind, when i try to sync, my previous commits will discard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to:

1. Add the upstream as a remote and fetch to get the last changes from upstream project: `git remote add upstream https://github.com/upstream_project/url`
2. Rebase your changed on top of the upstream branch you want to merge into (seems `main`): `git rebase upstream/main`
3. `git push --force-with-lease` to your github remote and it will update the PR.